# nodejs with ssl (https to https) Error: unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: node.js, api, rest, ssl, nginx

i have two projects in the same server, 1st:
php with nginx in port 443, thats an api rest.
2nd: nodejs in port 80 this is a consuming of rest api.

1st and 2nd works alone fine and both have a ssl certificate but when i try to access api from node js to api returns exception

> Error: unable to verify the first certificate

if both applications use "http" works fine, and node can access to api rest. to consume api rest in node i use "[node-rest-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client)" i try use this args but doesn't work:

```
connection:{
        secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2,
        ciphers: 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH:!AESGCM',
        honorCipherOrder: true
    }
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: how did you access api from node.js ? `https://api.domain.com/api` or `https://localhost/api/`

Comment: https://api.domain.com/here-all-routes i try with https://api.domain.com:443/ but doesn´t works

Comment: It means you're using local DNS for api.domain.com, so please check /etc/hosts file, there are any record about: api.domain.com ip_address

Comment: In the same server, I think you should use http because traffic you call API, they donot go to the outside the server, so it isnot related security issues

Comment: But api is a global service anyone can use it, for that reason is https. the problem is nodejs (i discovered recently this). I think it's a problem between nginx and node.